# Chat message status indicator

Tags: feature-request, chat

When in chat, sometimes my messages fail to send due to the anti-flood or a network timeout.

Often this happens after I've written a follow-up message which in turn shows the messages in the wrong order after clicking `retry`, making them incoherent.

Would it be possible to maybe add a small spinner or indicator to the message which shows when the message has been successfully submitted, kind of how Facebook does it?

[image]
<sub>(source: [xbenjii.co.uk](https://xbenjii.co.uk/i/mZVXV))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Right now an indicator exists, but a more visual one should be added.

The message appears green when not delivered as follows:

[image]

It then appears black (normal colour) when delivered:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there was smth else...

Comment: Yea this is veeeeery subtle, it's a very obscure feature that only a select few experienced users know about, because of how subtle the color difference is. Maybe it's not intended to be a prominent indicator, but it's almost impossible to learn about this if you are not asking around questions like OP posted.